# Event that fires only when user moves the splitter?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, splitter

I have a VB .NET form with a splitter control on it, and I want to save its position between program runs.  I am currently handling the SplitterMoved event and storing the SplitterDistance.  Then on program startup, I set the SplitterDistance to the saved value.

However, sometimes the program resizes the splitter, raising the SplitterMoved event and overwriting my saved distance.  I have several splitters over multiple tabs in a tab control, and any time the user goes to a new tab for the first time, the SplitterMoved event fires.

Is there an event I can use that will only fire when the user moves the splitter, and not when the program moves the splitter?  I tried MouseUp, but when that event fires, the new SplitterDistance is not yet set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a separate event as the splitter *has* been moved.

Given that the spliter should be in the same place as it was before it shouldn't change the value you have stored. Are you checking the `sender` object to make sure you're updating the correct splitter position?

Answer (score 0):

The SplitterEventArgs provide both the splitter coordinates and the mouse coordinates.

I'd assume that for non-user instigated SplitterMoved events, the Mouse coordinates would be out of range.

Comment: SplitterEventArgs has same arguments, it does not depend if it fired by user or size change.